# Java Collections clone operation

Tags: java

why there is no clone operation for collections in Java ?
There must be able to copy the contents of the collections to a new collection and modify the second collection without affecting the first one

Answer (score 3):

Every collection has a constructor taking another collection as argument:

```
List<Foo> original = ...;
List<Foo> clone = new ArrayList<>(original);
```